# Trouble with getting User Id through ResouceServer::OwnerId()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I have implemented Oauth 2 in laravel 4 from [lucadegasperi's github](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel). In one of my controllers I tried to retrieve the user id using ResourceServer::getOwnerId() but I am not able to do so.

My **routes.php** looks as follows:

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function() {
    return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
});

Route::group(array('before'=>'oauth'), function(){

    Route::post('exp', 'ExpController@store');
});
```

The **controller** looks thus (for the time being):

```
class ExpController extends \BaseController {
    public function store() {
           //
           $exp = ResourceServer::getOwnerId();

           return Response::json(
                  array(
                      'message' => $exp
                  ),
                  200 
                )->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
    }
}
```

My log gives me the following error:

```
    production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\
FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'ResourceServer' not found'
```

Where could I go wrong? Did I miss something?

Comment: Is your controller inside a namespace? If yes, use `\ResourceServer` or add a `use` statement

Comment: I am so sorry but I didn't understand as to what does controller being inside a namespace mean...??

Comment: In your controller (presumably `ExpController.php`) do you have `namespace ...;` at the top?

Comment: No... Not all... I have pretty much copy-pasted the whole controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the usage of the package has changed a bit (at least since I used it) There's no `ResourceServer` Facade anymore. But you can call this instead:

```
Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
```

Comment: Need to ask you this... Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId() works well if the grant_type is password... And what should I use for client_credentials grant_type...?? Because Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId() gives me an error message for client_credentials....

Comment: Puh. Don't know the answer off the top of my head... Will take a look at it later.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find anything and don't have the time to dig in further. Maybe ask a new question on SO? Good luck figuring it out :)